# JavaScript Memory leak using setInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory, memory-leaks

Im having trouble with my javascript application leaking memory. I've looked up things online and I seem to have closed out any memory alocation in the setInterval loop by using the

```
variableX = null
```

technique. But the application is still leaking memory somehow, can anyone point out what might be causing this leak? Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple markers</title>
  <style>
     html, body, #map-canvas {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px
     }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>

     function initialize() {
         var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.46949, -80.54661);
         var lat = 0;
         var long = 0;
         var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 16,
             center: myLatlng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }

         function loadXMLDoc() {
             var xhr;
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
             } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                 xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
             xhr.open("GET", "coordinates.txt", true);
             xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                 if (this.readyState == 4) {
                     var textfileString = this.responseText;
                     var longLatString = textfileString.split(',');
                     lat = parseFloat(longLatString[0])
                     long = parseFloat(longLatString[1])
                     textfileString = null
                     longLatString = null
                 }
             }
             xhr.send();
             xhr = null
         }
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatlng,
             map: map,
             title: 'Hello World!'
         });
         setInterval(function () {
             loadXMLDoc()
             var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
             marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
             newLatLng = null
         }, 16);
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the evidence that it is leaking memory?

Comment: Running this in a browser within my application, and when the application is left running it shows memory continuously increasing in task manager and if left for a very long time the program will eventually crash.

Comment: Wait... you're making a new XHR request every 16 milliseconds?

Comment: I'm using the Webkit browser for C# winforms found here: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: ...and FYI, your `lat` and `long` are not going to be received yet from the `XHR` request when the `var newLatLng = new google.maps...` runs

Comment: @cookiemonster I thought it was disallocated using the line "xhr = null" at the end of the loadXMLDoc() function?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out each line in SetInterval to see which one causes the leak? Then dig into the cause until you get to a single line.

Comment: @cookiemonster the app already works and is fully functional, just trying to fix the memory leak.

Comment: @user1296932: sure, but you're still sending out requests faster than the can possibly come back, and there'll never be a situation where the new `LatLng()` object waits for the XHR response. ...If there's a memory leak and crashes, it's not fully functional. You seem to have a misunderstanding of asynchronous coding.

Comment: Instead of spamming from a timer, you may want to use a callback when the ajax request completes to send a new request (possibly after a small delay).

Comment: And google might start liking you

Comment: @acarlon is right. Don't use `setInterval`. Just relocate the code to the `onreadystatechange` inside the end of the `if (this.readyState == 4) {`

Answer (score 3):

You're sending a new `XMLHttpRequest` without waiting for the old one to complete. If the response takes longer than 16 milliseconds to be received (which it probably will), the "request queue" will grow, causing a memory leak.

Sending requests *nonstop* is a bad idea. If you need a constant stream of coordinates, pack multiple coordinates into one response and send a new request only when your previous one has completed:

```
function getCoordinates() {
    ...
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        ...
        setTimeout(getCoordinates, 30000);
    }
}
```

Better yet, use Websockets.

Comment: May not be a bad idea to clarify that the `setTimeout` should be behind the `readystate==4` condition. You do imply it in your first sentence though.

Comment: I assumed 16ms would be enough time to process the majority of requests because its just pulling information from a local file?

Also doing it this way defeats the purpose of the app, its supposed to be updating the user realtime of gps coordinates being sent, having position updates delayed 30 seconds isn't acceptable in this application.

Comment: @user1296932: Then use Websockets. HTTP requests aren't "realtime".